# Test for pixel at x, y in pygame Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to create Langton's Ant in pygame.
I need to test if a pixel is on, or off.
I want to do something like this:

```
import pygame

def pixel(x, y, r, g, b):
    surface.set_at((x, y), (r, b, g))

while not windowClosed:

    pixel(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    pixel = windowDisplay.get_at((0, 0))
    if pixel == (0, 0, 0):
        print("Oh yeah!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`surface.set_at((0, 0), (0, 0, 0))`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_at) sets the color of the pixel at the coordinates `(0, 0)` to black.

Use `pixel = surface.get_at((0, 0))` to get the color of the pixel at `(0, 0)`. `get_at` returns a `pygame.Color` object and in this case `pixel` has the value `(0, 0, 0, 255)` (the fourth number is the alpha value which you can omit if you want to compare it with a tuple). So if you want to check if a pixel is black, just write:

```
pixel = surface.get_at((0, 0))
if pixel == (0, 0, 0):
    print("Oh yeah!")
```

Comment: [Chapter 16](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=array_backed_grids&lang=de#section_16) of Program Arcade Games about grids might be interesting to you.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it later when I have time!

Comment: Oh, it didn't work. I tried it, but it said something about not being able to create "pygame.Color". I tried upvoting btw, but I think I need a certain "level" or something.

Comment: I declared the "pixel" variable inside a while loop, but I doubt that it makes a difference. I'm new to Python and pygame.

Comment: Could you show me a minimal example? Just add it to the question for the moment.

Comment: Updated! Sorry to keep you waiting for that long.

Comment: Oops, that "windowDisplay" was supposed to be "surface"

Comment: You're overriding the name of the `pixel` function with the `pygame.Color` object here: `pixel = surface.get_at((0, 0))`. That means you can't call the `pixel` function anymore, because it's now a color. Rename either the function (for example to `set_pixel`) or the `pixel` variable.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think overriding a function was possible. I'll make sure to try that later!
I've got to go to sleep now.